# How to convert List to specified List<T> where T comes from CodeDom

Tags: c#, dynamic, codedom

```
Assembly assembly = cr.CompiledAssembly;
object instance = assembly.CreateInstance("Models.Test", true, BindingFlags.Default, null, null, null, null);
Type instType = instance.GetType();
instType.GetProperty("Code").SetValue(instance, "Code_value", null);
instType.GetProperty("Name").SetValue(instance, "Name_value", null);
instType.GetProperty("Address").SetValue(instance, "Address_value", null);

var listType = typeof(List<>);
var genericListType = listType.MakeGenericType(instType);
var instGenericListType = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);

instGenericListType.Add(instance);
```

I have a `IList`, now I want to convert `List<Models.Test>`, how can I do that? Do I have a way specified type when I call `MakeGenericType`

Comment: Does the method takes generic parameter `T`? Post method declaration too.

Comment: Hi Sriram: Method isn't received T, just is received string properties(',' separator for each item). Models.Test class with properties string I dynamic generate from CodeDom. Is is possible to convert to dynamic class?

Comment: Without knowing `T` at compile time you cant cast it to `List<T>`. If you can provide more context(Why you want to cast, What you are going to do with `instGenericListType`) it will be easy to answer.

Comment: Hi Sriram: thank you for your responding, you are right, without knowing T at compile time, we can not cast it.